# Is there a Pear caching proxy server?

Tags: php, pear

I'm doing some devops work, and am frequently having to bring up a machine and install a bunch of Pear packages from different locations.

These different locations [go offline](http://isup.me/phpdoc.org) somewhat frequently (maybe a few times a week). Too frequently for my sanity, anyway.

It would be handy to have some kind of caching proxy server I host and run myself that I go to for every Pear package. If it doesn't have the package, it goes out and fetches it. This would reduce load on many other servers. I'd also get a level of assurance that I'll still have access to packages if an upstream went down forever.

Does such software exist? Pyrus? I can't even figure out what problem Pyrus solves, but it doesn't appear to solve mine.

This kind of package proxying/caching is similar to what [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/go) does in Java/Maven-land.

Answer (score 2):

Pyrus is intented to be the PEAR installer for PHP5.3+. Some newer PEAR2 packages require it. But it is not the solution to caching.

---

I think the easiest way would be to download the packages **and their dependencies** once from remote server and then loacally install the packages. Here comes an example using the `Benchmark` package:

```
wget 'http://your.cache.server/package/Benchmark-1.2.9.tgz'
tar xf Benchmark-1.2.9.tgz
cp package.xml Benchmark-1.2.9
sudo pear install package.xml
```

---

Another way would be to just use a **caching HTTP proxy server**, as PEAR uses HTTP for downloads. Squid might already fit your needs.

---

You can also use [pirum](http://pirum.sensiolabs.org/). It is a PEAR channel server software, meaning you can setup your own PEAR repository. Having it, you could simulate the remote channels servers (which are frequently down) on your own:

- download the packages you need from that remote channels and install in your own
- point the domains to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts, setup apache vhosts for them
- use pyrus to setup a channel server for each of that domains and add the packages to them

Comment: @Adam Sorry there where a little naming conflict in my answer. I meant `pirum` no `pyrus`.. Check my update

Answer (score 1):

Pyrus is a re-written PEAR installer for PHP 5.3+.

There is a PEAR channel mirroring tool called "MiniPEAR" at https://github.com/c9s/MiniPear

Simply downloading a package does not give you all dependencies, so it's not a real solution.